# Make loop with progress of int value

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a dilemma with a loop.

I have a very simpel Android game and in that game i have a loop that draws images.

100 images will be drawn but now it draws all of the images at once so the game is lagging. If i set it to draw 10-20 images it runs fine.

So i wonder if i can draw/loop the images as i progress? I have a score in my game so maybe i could use that to listen for a certain nr and then draw more etc...

Here is my loop for the images

```
public class MainGame extends Screen {
 int score = 0;
Random rand = new Random();

int total_kos = 100;
 float kos_positions[][] = new float[total_kos][2];
    StartGame();
}

public void StartGame() {


    score = 0;


    for(int i =0;i<total_kos;i++){
          kos_positions[i][0] = 600 + i*300 ;
          kos_positions[i][1] =  rand.nextFloat() * 0.3f + 0.4f;
    }
}
```

I have tried with

```
int total_kos =  score + 1;
```

But that gave me nothing else but 1 image

Comment: try like this, int total_kos=0; (or the value you are using) total_kos = total_kos + (score + 1); Or ++score;

Comment: You can look for time factor or can use timer class to increment no of your kos with time... One more thing I would like to suggest is for performance look to work with game engiene like Andengiene

Comment: Ok i've tried to add
    total_kos = total_kos + (++score);
and 
    total_kos = total_kos + (score + 1);
to StartGame()

But nothing else is drawn except my first kos...
http://stackoverflow.com/users/3036759/atul-o-holic